# Application of group theory to combinatorics

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

Let k be a positive integer. In how many ways one can color the edges of an
equilateral triangle using k colors (two coloring schemes are considered the same
if one can be obtained from the other via some symmetry of the triangle)?

Comment: You may want to look up Polya-Redfield counting/ Burnside lemma.

Comment: Can you expand? What other restrictions are there? ty batman.

Comment: Use burnside's lemma to count the number of orbits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since there are only 3 vertices to consider, the symmetry rule implies that 
the order of the colors is insignificant. If all three vertices have the same color,
there are $k$ possibilities. If two vertices have the same color and the third another,
there are $k(k-1)$ possibilities and if all three are different the number is 
 $ \binom{k}{3} $.  Thus, the total is $ k^2 + \binom{k}{3}. $

Comment: you treat this problem as a combination problem, but I prefer to the way using abstract Algebra.